# Reorder Div tags based on an attribute

Tags: css, html

Thanks in advance for your help, I've been using CSS for a while, but have no clue on Jquery/Javascript. I'm creating a tour website, I have a long list of tours that clients can book on, however I want a way that they can be ordered by price and duration. Each tour is in a separate div tag. I've listed a simplified version of the code im using below. Can anyone let me know if it's possible to make a set of links above the div tags that will reorder them based on Price, Duration or alphabetically (depending on what link is clicked)

```
<div class="result" price = "749" duration="8" Name="Basecamp">Info about tour 1 goes here</div>

<div class="result" price = "2099" duration="19" Name="Cycle Adventure">Info about tour 2 goes here</div>

<div class="result" price = "1099" duration="25"Name="Family Adventure">Info about tour 3 goes here</div>

 <div class="result" price = "3014" duration="18" Name="Luxury Basecamp">Info about tour 3 goes here</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple solution. I took a few liberties on your HTML--I wrapped the <div> elements in a <section> element, and prepended 'data-' onto to your result, price, and duration attributes in your <div> elements.

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/databass/Yh2L3/

HTML:

```
<button data-sort='price'>Sort By Price</button>
<button data-sort='duration'>Sort By Duration</button>
<button data-sort='name'>Sort By Name</button>
<section id="tours">
    <div class="result" data-price="749" data-duration="8" data-name="Basecamp">Info about tour 1 goes here</div>
    <div class="result" data-price="2099" data-duration="19" data-name="Cycle Adventure">Info about tour 2 goes here</div>
    <div class="result" data-price="1099" data-duration="25" data-name="Family Adventure">Info about tour 3 goes here</div>
    <div class="result" data-price="3014" data-duration="18" data-name="Luxury Basecamp">Info about tour 4 goes here</div>
</section>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('button').on('click', function (event) {
    var divElements = $('#tours div'),
        sortType = $(this).data('sort');

    divElements.sort(function (a, b) {

        a = $(a).data(sortType);
        b = $(b).data(sortType);

    // compare
        if (a > b) {
            return 1;
        } else if (a < b) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });

    $('#tours').empty();
    $.each(divElements, function (i, divElement) {
        $('#tours').append(divElement.outerHTML);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a really nice little JQuery plugin called TinySort that works well and has lots of great examples:

The URL:  http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

Go down to the Sorting Tables section to see how to sort multiple values.